# Unexpected token G in JSON at position 0 with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, angular5, measurement-protocol

I am trying to use the Measurement Protocol from Google Analytics in my working Angular 5 project. I put the Google Analytics Universal code in `index.html` and I am making http calls to the service like this

**index.html**

```
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y', {
      'cookieDomain': 'none'
    });
    // console.log(window.dataLayer);
  </script>
```

Service launching http calls

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataService } from './Data.service';

@Injectable()
export class AnalyticsService {

  private anUID = 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y';
  private analyticsURL = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private datos: DataService) { }

  public pageViewLista(): void {
    this.http.get(
      this.setScreenViewUrl(
        encodeURI('Lista de empresas'))).subscribe((data) => {
          console.log('Received data from GAnalytics: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    );
  }

  protected setScreenViewUrl (pantalla: string): string {
    const constructUrl = `${this.analyticsURL}v=1&t=screenview&tid=${this.anUID}&cid=${this.datos.id}&an=${this.datos.app}&dt=${pantalla}&cd=${pantalla}`;
    return constructUrl;
  }

}
```

The problem is what Google returns an strange error and I dont know what it means nor the reason of this error. Am I doing a bad implementation?

Error from Google:

> ERROR
>
> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=...",  ok: false, …}
>
> error : {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token G in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttp…, text: "GIF89a�����,D;"}

It seems like if the server was tryings to JSON parse a GIF image. Cant find anything in the documentation and Google shows no information.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Analytics endpoint for data collection returns a transparent gif file (and it returns a 200 status for everything but server errors, so you can't use this to see if your data is actually tracked). A gif cannot be decoded as JSON.

If you want a JSON response you would need to use the [endpoint for the GA debugger](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits) (google-analytics.com/debug/collect). That would give info if your payload is valid, but would not track the call.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I dont figure how can I transform the subscription from HttpClient into an image. I am trying to return an `Observable<Image>` but still gets same error

Comment: I don't know much about angular, I can just tell you that you cannot JSON.stringify a gif image (i.e. that this is not a GA error message, that's a simply Javascript error), which is what you asked.  Perhaps you should edit/amend your question (or ask a new one).

Comment: JSON stringify was added after getting the error. I am trying to blob the image. Thanks a lot for your help.